# Download data from Wikipedia page

Tags: c++, api, http, get, wikipedia

I'm trying to download data from Wikipedia. I send a GET request, but the return status - "HTTP 301 redirection". Now I need to parse that to get the target URL, and from there I can access the article content.
I do the parse but but I cannot access to the article content. I appreciate your help if you can help me to get to the article content.

code -

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string query = "Google";
//int depth = 0;

// Initialize Dependencies to the Windows Socket.
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
    cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
    system("pause");
}

struct addrinfo hints;
ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

/* connect to wikipedia //and download the article */
static const char wiki_host[] = "en.wikipedia.org";
struct addrinfo* targetAdressInfo = NULL;
DWORD getAddrRes = getaddrinfo(wiki_host, NULL, &hints, &targetAdressInfo);
if (getAddrRes != 0 || targetAdressInfo == NULL)
{
    cout << "Could not resolve the Host Name" << endl;
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

SOCKADDR_IN sockAddr;
sockAddr.sin_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*) targetAdressInfo->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
sockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);

freeaddrinfo(targetAdressInfo);

SOCKET webSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (webSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cout << "Creation of the Socket Failed" << endl;
    system("pause");
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

if (connect(webSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&sockAddr, sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0)
{
    cout << "Could not connect";
    system("pause");
    closesocket(webSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

string http_query = "GET /wiki/" + query + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
http_query += string("Host: ") + wiki_host + "\r\n";
http_query += "\r\n\r\n";
if (send(webSocket, http_query.c_str(), http_query.length(), 0) == -1) {
    cout << "Could not send the request to the Server" << endl;
    system("pause");
    closesocket(webSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

/* prepare to fetch the wiki article */

string response = "";

while (true) {
    static char recv_buffer[4096];
    const int bytes_read = recv(webSocket, recv_buffer, sizeof(recv_buffer) - 1, 0);
    if (!bytes_read) {
        break;
    }
    if (bytes_read == -1) {
        closesocket(webSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    recv_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
    response += recv_buffer;
};

/* finished with the socket */

closesocket(webSocket);
WSACleanup();

/* parse the http response headers */

size_t cursor = 0;
string response_content;
vector<std::string> response_headers;
const size_t headers_end = response.find("\r\n\r\n");

while (true) {
    const size_t line_end = response.find("\r\n", cursor);
    if (line_end == std::string::npos) { /* probably due to http error */
        break;
    }
    response_headers.push_back(response.substr(cursor, line_end - cursor));
    if (line_end == headers_end) { /* found content */
        response_content = response.substr(headers_end + 4); /* skip \r\n\r\n */
        break;
    }
    cursor = line_end + 2; /* skip \r\n */
}


// print the respone 
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(response); i++){
    cout << response[i];
}

/* print response_content not work 
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(response); i++){
    cout << response_content[i];
}*/
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't try to implement HTTP yourself, either use the [Windows WinInet library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [the cURL library](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). It will make life *much* simpler when fetching "pages" from web-servers.

Comment: I suggest you use a high level HTTP client library like curl instead of writing one by hand. That's easier and less error-prone. Except you want to learn to write one by hand.

Comment: excellent API's, but I learn to write them by hand ( :

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by saying "I do the parse but but I cannot access to the article content". What you need to do when you get 301 status is to look at "Location" header you received back. That header contains the URL you can use to fetch the content you are looking for.